# What are my expansion options?

Tags: endless-legend

While I'm open to recommendations, I first need to make sure I understand the game mechanics of founding new cities. I started in the bottom left of the pangea in Strard.

[image: Strard]

I've expanded my initial city five times. I had just learned about leveling up a district before the last expansion and was lucky to get two-for-one. But I just got a quest to found a new city and level up both it and one of its new districts.

> Within your Empire, raise a new City Center and a new District to their Level 2.

However, all seven regions surrounding mine--first ring of Oyvinn, Horlaken, and Menavin and second ring of Ipedan, Dels, Lodera, and Garint--contain enemy cities. And the user's manual states that each region may host only one city.

> Each region can host exactly one city, never more. It you want to conquer a region which is already claimed by another empire, you must first capture its city.

**Since Kentamys has no city yet, to expand must I either take a settler there (or another region without a city) or conquer one of the regions listed above.** Furthermore, will I be able to complete the quest by conquering an existing city?

Comment: I do know using a Settler will complete the quest.  I don't know about conquering another city, though.

Comment: I have since conquered the three adjacent cities and leveled up the third City Center, achieving the quest. As I had already leveled up a few Districts, it appears the quest only requires one City Center and one District in any two cities (may be the same city)--founded or conquered.

Comment: If that hadn't worked you could have conquered one, then razed it creating a settler, then resettled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since confirmed the rule in the user's manual: you cannot found a new city in a region that already contains a city.

**Recommendation:** Expand into nearby regions before they fill up.

Comment: You could also use "Salting the Earth" on a captured city, and start a new city in the province. Just make sure the AI doesn't outrace you to build a new city there.